# Simple space trimming program

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I have this java code to trim all spaces in a String for me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class trimSpace {
   public static void main( String[] args ) {

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   String str;

   System.out.print("Please enter a string:");
   str = input.nextLine();

   System.out.println("The result is : ");

   char[] charArray = new char[A.length()];
   for(int i=0;i<A.length();i++){
      if (A.charAt(i) != ' ') { //This line should ignore the space in the str
        charArray[i] = A.charAt(i); 
        System.out.print(charArray[i]);
      }     
   }
   //Expected output [j,a,v,a,,,]
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(charArray)); //Output [j," ",A," ",V," ",A]
   }
}
```

If I insert "J A V A" into str, the charArray still include the spaces after printing i.e. [j," ",A," ",V," ",A] What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why don't you use `replaceAll()` and remove all spaces?

Comment: Yea, i know there are something like that. However, im trying to use loops to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the "correct characters" into the **same index** where you found them. That way you *skip* the spaces and leave them.

```
    charArray[i] = A.charAt(i); 
    System.out.print(charArray[i]);
```

You need to add a `counter` in `charArray`:

```
    charArray[counter++] = A.charAt(i);
```

That way you'll only advance in `charArray` if the input was *not* a space. Or more complete:

```
  int counter = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<A.length();i++){
  if (A.charAt(i) != ' ') { //This line should ignore the space in the str
    charArray[counter++] = A.charAt(i); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
String str = "J A V A";
str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

Comment: That's correct - but the way the question was set up this is probably an assignment to learn something about arrays and loops...

Comment: Yep, im using loops to get a clearer understanding of using loops. Thanks for answering though.